# Make input reverse writing

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I need to implement an input field with some restrictions. 
First, it needs to have default zeros and max length = 4
  and the procedure of usage is following:

initial state of input: 
0000
start typing (character):
1
after state of input:
0001
following typing:
2
after state of input:
0012

In order to have default zeros I use Angualar Ui Mask ui-mask-placeholder

here is my input

```
<input type="text" ui-mask-placeholder="0000" ui-mask="9999" ng-model="$ctrl.storeId"  maxlength="4" required />
```

what I need is to make input caret to be placed in that way to write in reverse that the zeros could always be before typing numbers

My attempt to find solution was:
make a directive that

```
<input type="text" ui-mask-placeholder="0000" ui-mask="9999" ng-model="$ctrl.storeId"  modify-input-with-zeros maxlength="4" required />


const modifyInputWithZerosFactory = () => {
  'ngInject'
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
       var maxValLength = parseInt(attrs.maxlength)
       var step = 0
       element[0].selectionStart = maxValLength - 1
       element.on('input', function() {
         step = step + 1
         element[0].selectionStart = maxValLength - step
       })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for any length as your requiement. Just give the max length value in **controller**

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">

   <input type="text" ng-model="num" ng-keypress="makeInputReverse($event)" maxlength="{{maxLength}}"/>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.num = "";
  $scope.maxLength = 4;

  for(var i=0; i<$scope.maxLength; i++){$scope.num = $scope.num+'0'}
  var noOfZeros = $scope.num;

  $scope.makeInputReverse = function(event){
    if($scope.num.length == $scope.maxLength && $scope.num[0] != '0'){
      event.preventDefault();
    } else if(event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57){
          event.preventDefault();
    } else{
      if($scope.num.length <= $scope.maxLength || $scope.num == noOfZeros){
        if(!$scope.num) $scope.num = 0;
        $scope.num = (parseInt($scope.num) * 10) + parseInt(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
        $scope.num = noOfZeros + $scope.num;
        $scope.num = ($scope.num).slice($scope.num.length-$scope.maxLength, $scope.num.length);
      }
    }
  }

})
```

Here we have the working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2cJrUGYcygvM9i6wKx5

**Note:**

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.num" ng-keypress="$ctrl.makeInputReverse($event)" maxlength="4"/>
```

But if you want to use like `$ctrl.num` you must write the controller As syntax that is `ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl"` and change all the occurrences of  `$scope.num` to `this.num` and `$scope.akeInputReverse` to `this.akeInputReverse` in the **controller**.